# problem with list-style-type

Tags: sass, sencha-touch

I have a scss file that defines a list-style-type.  An excerpt of this file is as follows:

```
$orange: #c53830;
```

..

```
ul.list1 {
    list-style-type:circle;
    color:$orange;
}
```

In my javascript I have

```
    html: '<ul class="list1"><li>some words</li><li>some more words</li></ul>'
```

The color is being applied, but I am not getting a bulleted list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sencha-touch.css specifies:

```
li
{
  list-style:none;
}
```

Try adding the following to your own scss:

```
list-style:circle;
```

as well.

Also do you have the link sencha-touch.css before your template css so you're overriding it correctly?